# plyr multiple columns in 1 call

Tags: r, plyr

Here is the structure of my data:

```
> str(highered.tweets)
'data.frame':   2950 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ created_at  : POSIXlt, format: "2012-02-13 20:41:36" "2012-02-13 20:37:00" ...
 $ from_user   : chr  "feministtexican" "OzGrrl09" "LuanaClarke" "LostBookEnds" ...
 $ from_user_id: chr  "68253996" "63451221" "273757811" "118199557" ...
 $ tweet_idstr : chr  "169234804729069570" "169233649844236288" "169233398240526337" "169232836795187203" ...
 $ text        : chr
```

Here are my functions that I was attempting to pass to plyr:

```
NTWEETS <- function(x) nrow(x)
NUNIQUE <- function(x) length(unique(x$from_user_id))
```

This works fine:

```
ddply(highered.tweets[,c(1,3)], .(format(created_at, "%j%H" )), NTWEETS)
ddply(highered.tweets[,c(1,3)], .(format(created_at, "%j%H" )), NUNIQUE)
```

However this fails:

```
ddply(highered.tweets[,c(1,3)], .(format(created_at, "%j%H" )), transform,
                      NTWEETS,
                      NUNIQUE)

Error in as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : invalid 'tz' value
```

Any help will be much appreciated.  I am just starting to use plyr and I am beginning to realize it took me way too long to dive into this great library.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
summary_tweets <- function(x){
  num_tweets    <- NROW(x)
  unique_tweets <- length(unique(x$from_user_id))
  data.frame(num_tweets, unique_tweets)
}

ddply(highered.tweets[,c(1,3)], .(format(created_at, "%j%H" )), summary_tweets)
```

Comment: Great, thanks.  The part I don't quite get is why it works fine indivdiually, but when I include transform, it fails when I simply want to do multiple transformations.  Regardless, this works great.

Answer (score 1):

If in doubt, read the documentation?  ;-)

It is pretty easy: use `.(var1, var2, ...)`. Here is an example.  We the good old mtcars data:

```
R> head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

and for example's sake redo a conditional mean of all variable conditional on the combinations of transmission (`am` as in automatic or not) and gears:

```
R> ddply(mtcars, .(am,gear), colMeans)
      mpg     cyl    disp      hp    drat     wt   qsec   vs am gear    carb
1 16.1067 7.46667 326.300 176.133 3.13267 3.8926 17.692 0.20  0    3 2.66667
2 21.0500 5.00000 155.675 100.750 3.86250 3.3050 20.025 1.00  0    4 3.00000
3 26.2750 4.50000 106.688  83.875 4.13375 2.2725 18.435 0.75  1    4 2.00000
4 21.3800 6.00000 202.480 195.600 3.91600 2.6326 15.640 0.20  1    5 4.40000
R>
```